# Why do I have to unlock an iPad to charge it?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, charging

When I plug in the "iPad (6th generation) Wi-Fi + Cellular" to the MacBook, it always says "unlock this iPad to use accessories."  What it doesn't say is that it also won't charge until I do so.  Took me several times to figure this out.  (Has a cover, so I didn't see the message.)

But the iPhone 7+ doesn't do that.  Both have IOS 12.4, so there must be a setting that I am not recognizing.  Or are there distinct unlabeled "flavors" of IOS?

How can I make it start charging as soon as plugged in, even if screen is locked?

Comment: Calling the MacBook an "accessory" is also a bit weird.

Answer (score 4):

The 'unlock to charge' is a new security feature since iOS 11.4. If you charge from a device that asks to communicate over USB you have to opt in. 
Alternatively, just plug in to a 'dumb' charger or [employ a USB data block dongle / condom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juice_jacking#Mitigation) to physically prevent “juice jacking”. If there's no potential data connection, there's no restriction on charging or prompt to unlock.

To elaborate a bit, this design prevents hardware USB devices read data from your device. Remember when the FBI wanted to get into some guy's phone & tried to force Apple through the courts to 'let them in'? This is the current state of play in the hacker 'war'.

It can be disabled if you don't think you have any data on there worthy of government or black hat hacker intrusion.

Apple KB - [Using USB accessories with iOS 11.4.1 and later](https://support.apple.com/HT208857)

Settings > Face [Touch] ID & Passcode > USB Accessories

Comment: If it’s an IOS feature, why did it never happen on the iPhone?  And how does preventing _charging_ protect the data?

Comment: It has even happened with a non-data USB charger built into an AC wall socket.

Comment: My iPad charges without any other action when plugged into a wallwart... @WGroleau  and the cover can be closed or open...

Comment: " If it’s an IOS feature, why did it never happen on the iPhone? And how does preventing charging protect the data? "  @WGroleau You might not have seen this on your iPhone because it is running an older iOS that lacks this security feature.  A well behaved USB device will draw only 100 mA before the host computer communicates with it and allows more power draw.  Blocking all USB traffic prevents requests for more power.  This protects the iPhone by not allowing any data transfer that might exploit a security flaw such as a buffer overflow.

Comment: " It has even happened with a non-data USB charger built into an AC wall socket. " @WGroleau  USB chargers are getting "smarter" and may contain a microcontroller to negotiate power.  This is not required for charging as specified by USB-BC & BrickID used by Apple for "dumb" chargers.  Apple and others support "smart" charging by other protocols.  E.g. PowerIQ chargers are claimed to identify the device plugged in to optimize charging, this would require some communication to tell the iPhone that it can provide 5V/2.4A of power as well as provide different volts and amps to different devices.

Comment: Both iPads and both iPhones had the latest IOS.  And it only happened on one of the iPads.  And it doesn’t happen every time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has changed in more recent times to a "Trust" method. It asks just once. My phone certainly hasn't asked to be unlocked for anything other than file transfer in a long time.

Comment: "Allow access when locked" is NOT enabled on any of our devices, yet this happens consistently on one iPad, inconsistently on the other, and at the time of posting, never on either iPhone.  However, recently, it has started to happen on the iPhones.  So, although this answer sounds right, there's still something weird.